# Electrostatics properties of charge

Tags: electrostatics

If in an electrically neutral body there are equal number of electrons and protons, then why not due to repulsions between the electrons - electrons and proton - proton the body does not tear apart into pairs of electrons and protons.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that there are repulsive forces operating in an atom. However, there are operative forces other than electromagnetic forces

The strong nuclear force is responsible for holding together the nucleus. At the distance scale of a proton the strong nuclear force is about 137 times stronger than the electromagnetic force. Therefore, the repulsive force due to both the protons being electrically positive is not strong enough to break the nucleus apart